# Spring @ExceptionHandler, @ResponseBody will not serialize/marshal response

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a very simple Spring rest controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/management")
@RestController
public class ManagementController {

    @Autowired
    private ManagementService managementService;

    @ExceptionHandler(DuplicateEntityException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    public ErrorDetail handleDuplicateEntityException(DuplicateEntityException ex) {
        return new ErrorDetail(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return managementService.createUser(user);
    } 
}
```

and the ErrorDetail class...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ErrorDetail {

    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "status")
    private int status;

    public ErrorDetail(String message, int status) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

and the custom exception, AAAException extends RuntimeException.

```
public class DuplicateEntityException extends AAAException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4223773548694193141L;

    public DuplicateEntityException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public DuplicateEntityException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

However the @ExceptionHandler will not marshall the ErrorDetail object I just get a 500, I can return a String from this method and it works. I'm sending  application/xml which is being correctly unmarshalled and marshalled via createUser method and I can't understand why the same isn't working for the @ExceptionHandler.

I'm using Spring 4.2.6.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your `DuplicateEntityException` class..

Comment: Added DuplicateEntityException

Comment: what if you annotate with @ReponseBody before the ErrorDetail return type in your method?

Comment: I still get a 500, I've even inspected org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver to check that it has the default message converter including the JAXB one, which it does.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have added the `exception handler` method within the `controller` because of that it will be triggered if you get an `exception` from that `controller` itself. use seperate class for exception handling ex:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {

@ExceptionHandler(DuplicateEntityException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorDetail handleDuplicateEntityException(DuplicateEntityException ex) {
   ExceptionRepresentation  body = new ExceptionRepresentation(ex.getMessage());
   HttpStatus responseStatus = HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
   return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionRepresentation>(body,responseStatus);
}
```

here using `@ControllerAdvice` will apply `exception` handling for every `controller.`

and the most important part is your methods should throw exceptions inorder for `@ExceptionHandler` to work change your method signature.

```
 public User createUser(@RequestBody User user) throw DuplicateEntityException{
    throw new DuplicateEntityException();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however the code I currently have does invoke the handleDuplicateEntityException method.

Comment: changed the method take a look at it. i removed  `@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)`  from the method

Comment: Unfortunately same behaviour even with @ControllerAdvice. I did however find that this was a bug in 3.0.1 but has subsequently been fixed https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6902

Comment: Just to clarify although the bug was fixed I cannot seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm embarrassed to say after debugging through the code the issue turns out to be a missing default constructor on the ErrorDetail class :-(